# Difference between ls() and objects()

Tags: r

What is the difference between the functions `ls()` and `objects()`?

I tried the following code and they give same result

```
a <- 1:10
b <- letters
c <- month.abb
```

Result:

```
> ls()
[1] "a" "b" "c"
> objects()
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Comment: Their source code is identical so I guess there is no difference.

Comment: Agree with @DavidArenburg. `all.equal(body(objects), body(ls))`
is `TRUE`. The `formals` are also the same

Comment: You can even check for yourself: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/base/R/attach.R#L198 (they are defined by the same function)

Comment: IT should have been obvious from the output of `?ls` that they're the same, but as others pointed out, checking the source proves it.

Comment: ls is easier to type :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are identical.  Looking at the source code they're literally just different names for the same code as can been seen here: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/bfe73ecd848198cb9b68427cec7e70c40f96bd72/src/library/base/R/attach.R#L200

The relevant snippet:

```
ls <- objects <-
    function (name, pos = -1L, envir = as.environment(pos), all.names = FALSE,
              pattern, sorted = TRUE)
{
```

We can also check that they have identical code from within R

```
> all.equal(body(objects), body(ls))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Obviously these snippets were taken from the comments given by hrbrmstr and BenBarnes but since they were hesitant to post an answer I put one up for reference.

Comment: Hi. Many thanks for your clarification. I just knew that i can view the code by simply run the function like ls / objects. And thanks to introduce the function all.equal to me.

Comment: In this case I would use `identical()` instead of `all.equal()` since the arguments are not numeric. The `all.equal()` function tests for near equality, which allows to check whether two floating point numbers are nominally equal.

Comment: @RHertel I think you have a good point in that `identical` might be more appropriate.  However, `all.equal` is not only just used for what you say.  If one was to use `all.equal` in a comparison though you would want to wrap it in `isTRUE`.  But in this case where we're just checking if they are equal and looking at that output directly in the console it doesn't matter.  On a side note if you want to know if things are equal and if they aren't then what is different about them then `all.equal` is the clearly better alternative. `all.equal(lm(wt~mpg,data=mtcars),lm(mtcars$wt~mtcars$mpg))`

Answer (score -1):

No difference..since in R all variables are considered as objects both function return same result